# iOS6 + Storyboard + Seem to be getting doubles

Tags: storyboard, ios6, viewcontroller

I have been having problems with my ios app ever since the upgrade to 6.  I'm sure that I have something configured wrong that up until now was hidden.

I am utilizing storyboard and have as my first view as just a regular old vanilla view controller.  This is my login page.  When you click on the "login" button it segues to "Tab Bar Controller" that has a bunch of tabs inside it including a tab that has a "logout" button.

EDIT: It's important to not that the login View Controller pushes a "MODAL" segue to the Tab Bar Controller.

The "logout" button will run a

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

that sends it back to the login view.  The user may then go ahead and relog in and so on...

The problem is that it seems as if every single time I go from login to the tab view I'm getting some duplicates.  The reason I know this is because in one of the tab views I have a

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

// Register observer to be called when download of data is complete
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:OBJECTS_LOADED_NOTIFICATION object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(coreDataViewController_downloadDataComplete:)
                                            name:OBJECTS_LOADED_NOTIFICATION
                                          object:nil];
```

Which is supposed to remove any observers already on the page and just add new ones.  However it just keeps adding in observers over and over and over.  Which leads me to believe that there are multiple versions of the page somewhere in memory.

Can someone PLEASE help!?  I have been trying to solve this thing for 4 straight days now with no results.  I'm sure it's something insanely stupid but I can't for the life of me figure out what.

Thanks
Matt

EDIT:
Per request I have added more code... :-)  I figured it was easier to just publish the whole project rather then post bits and pieces of it.

https://github.com/MCKRUZ/Iphone

Comment: You should add observers in viewWillAppear and remove them in viewWillDissappear in your case. Also, dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES is deprecated in iOS6.

Comment: Putting the observers in viewWillAppear and removing them in viewWillDisappear will help with the observers but doesn't get rid of my modal duplicate problem.  But that is a good tip thanks.

Comment: Also moving the code to the non-depreciated method didn't help either.

Comment: Deprecated methods could cause crash in the future... Can you add more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved / circumvented this problem.  Basically it is still recreating the VC's every single time I logout and log back in, however I reworked the code so that it doesn't matter if it does that since the object context I'm using is in a service and not on the page.

Still, it's odd behavior that apple wouldn't remove those instances of the VC's that aren't being used....I miss pageDidUnload...